# Calculate the sum of the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}^{}a_{n}x^n$ with $(a_n)$ periodic

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_{n})_{n\geq0}$ be a periodic sequence of period $T$ satisfying for all $n\geq0$: $a_{n+T}=a_{n}.$
> Calculate the sum of the series of coefficients $a_{n}$  with
> $$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$ for $|x|<R $, where $ R $  is the radius of convergence.

My try:

If $|x|<R$,  so $$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}a_{n}x^n+\sum_{n=T}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$
then by changing the summation index. $$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}a_{n}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+T}x^{n+T}$$
then using the periodicity
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}a_{n}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+T}=\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}a_{n}x^n+x^{T}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$

and finally $$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}a_{n}x^n+x^{T}S(x) \implies S(x)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}a_{n}x^n}{1-x^{T}}$$
Is it right or wrong? We are waiting for your answer. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are assuming $T$ is a positive integer, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks alright! It's technically not a rigorous proof, as you don't use limits or determine the radius of convergence (which should be about $1$). But if you know the ratio test, you can say that for $x < 1$ the ratio test says that it converges, and so it must converge to this!

Comment: Thank you sir for the clarification .. In a question that I imagined is close and asked how can I calculate the sum .. I have not made a guess about the convergence field Thanks for the tip@isaac Browne

Answer (score 0):

You can take the sum over the first period, let $S_T$, which is a finite number. Then the same terms repeat forever with an extra factor $x^{kT}$.

Hence, for $|x|<1$, the sum to infinity is

$$\frac{S_T}{1-x^T}.$$